# JPA fetch collection of subclass

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, inheritance, jpql

I have a case where we have an inheritance strategy like this (this is an example of the jpa wiki, our real example is an other business case :))

```
@Entity
@Inheritance
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="PROJ_TYPE")
@Table(name="PROJECT")
public abstract class Project {
  @Id
  private long id;
  ...
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("L")
public class LargeProject extends Project {
  @OneToMany
  private Set<Member> members;
}
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("S")
public class SmallProject extends Project {
}
```

I have a bunch of projects in my database and want to fetch all the projects at once, but by doing this, i also want to fetch my list of members at once.
Is there a way to do this with jpql? I know the TYPE annotation allows me to look at the type, but can I combine this with a JOIN FETCH?

I'm using hibernate, but don't want to downgrade back to the hibernate api if I don't need to

Comment: What happens now when you do entityManager.createQuery("from " + Project .class.getName()); ? Does it not fetch list of members?

Comment: Yeah, but it does not let me decide if I want to eager fetch it

Comment: @jelle you want them eager, and it fetches them eager. The problem is that you want them to be fecthed at once with a single executed SQL query. Without relying on the Hibernate API that is not possible, as the JPA specification does not force the implementations how the SQL queries are executed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the awnser. I already suspected that only JPA was not enough. What is the hibernate solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but I found a way by using only JPQL.
In your case :

```
SELECT p FROM Project p JOIN FETCH ((TREAT(p as LargeProject)).members)
```

Answer (score 1):

JPA and Hibernate doesn't support fetching associations from subclasses, unless the property is also present in the topmost member of the hierarchy. But according to this post (https://thorben-janssen.com/fetch-association-of-subclass/) you can work around this limitation by exploiting hibernate's level 1 cache mechanism.

In you case you'll fetch all instances of `Member` first, in a separated query, and then perform your query on `Project`, letting `LargeProject.members` to be `Lazy` loaded. Instead of performing `N + 1` SELECTs, hibernate will fetch those from the cache.